# Proof that every smooth manifold has a basis of regular coordinate balls (ISM, John M. Lee)

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In his *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* John M. Lee defines the notions of coordinate balls and regular coordinate balls. I'm trying to prove the claim that

> Every smooth manifold has a countable basis consisting of regular coordinate
> balls. (Ex. 1.20, page 15 of ISM).

Lee states, that the proof is an easy adaption of the proof that

> Every topological manifold has a countable basis consisting of pre-compact
> coordinate balls. (Lemma 1.10, p.8).

However, I don't really understand what the difference between both statements is (other than that in one case the charts are required to be smooth). Let me start with the relevant definitions.

- Let $M$ be a topological manifold and let $(U, \varphi)$ be a coordinate chart of $M$, i.e. $U$ is an open set of $M$ and $\varphi : U \to \varphi(U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism. Whenever $\varphi(U)$ is an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we call $U$ a **coordinate ball**.
- Now suppose $M$ is a *smooth* manifold. We say that a subset $B$ of $M$ is a **regular coordinate ball**, if there exists a smooth coordinate ball $B' \subseteq M$ containing $\overline{B}$ and the corresponding smooth coordinate map $\varphi: B' \to \mathbb{R}^n$ fulfills $$\varphi(B') = B_{r'}(0), \; \varphi(B) = B_{r}(0)\quad\text{and}\quad\varphi(\overline{B}) = \overline{B}_{r}(0)$$
  for some positive $r < r'$.

First, some observations: The condition $\varphi(B') = B_{r'}(0)$ just says that $B'$ is a smooth coordinate ball. I think the last condition $\varphi(\overline{B}) = \overline{B}_{r}(0)$ is probably unnecessary because $f(\overline{A})=\overline{f(A)}$ for any homeomorphism $f$. So the point seems to be, that the image of $B$ is an open ball that sits inside another open ball $B_{r'}(0)$ with same center. Lee remarks, that since $\overline{B}$ is homeomorphic to the compact set $\overline{B}_{r}(0)$ it must be compact in $M$ as well. Therefore any regular coordinate ball $B$ is pre-compact.

What adds to my confusion is the fact that, in the proof of Lemma 1.10 for any coordinate chart $(U, \varphi)$ of a given topological manifold, Lee starts by constructs a basis for $\varphi(U)$ the following way:
$$\mathcal{B} = \{ B_{r}(x)\,|\,x \in \mathbb{Q}^n, r \in \mathbb{Q}, B_{r'}(x)\subseteq \varphi(U)\;\;\text{for some }\; r' > r\}$$
So in some way he's already looking at balls who sit inside larger balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But i have no idea where and how i'm supposed to adapt this proof to show the results for regular coordinate balls. It would be highly appreciated if somebody could show me the first few steps, so that I can finish the proof myself.

Comment: Closure and image don't commute, even if the map is continuous (e.g. if $f(X)$ is dense in $Y$).

Comment: @Dog_69: You're right. But I think in this case my argument can be salvaged since $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism. And I think for homeomorphisms the statement is true. I'm gonna change the relevant part, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Also notice that a precompact coordinate ball may not be a regular coordinate ball ($\varphi(U)$ may not be centred at the origin).

Comment: True. Homeomorphisms can be characterised as _bijections which are continuous and closed_.

Comment: I don't have a copy of Lee's book but I'd say the only missing step is to move those balls to the origin. That changes nothing because sum is a smooth map.

Comment: @Dog_69: You mean that $\varphi(U)$ should be translated in such a manner, that $0 \in \varphi(U)$? And then instead of looking at all $B_{r}(x)$ we should define $\mathcal{B}$ by all balls $B_{r}(0)$ which fulfil the given criteria? If you want to have a quick look: most of the proof can be found on the bottom of page 8 at Google books: https://books.google.de/books?id=eqfgZtjQceYC&lpg=PA5&hl=de&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q&f=false But please don't feel obligated.

Comment: When it start to take ball with rational radius and rational center is just to argue that $\varphi(U)$ has a covering made of a $ \textbf{countable}$ number of coordinate precompact balls. I think you can start to take for all point $p\in M$ a big coordinate ball(if you want also precompact) and then find a smaller ball inside the first using the same coordinate chart.

Comment: I think I understand your hints now. The set $\mathcal{B}' = \{\varphi^{-1}(B_r(x))\,|\,B_r(x) \in \mathcal{B}\}$ is a basis for $U$ (since $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism). For any $B \in \mathcal{B}'$ we have $\varphi(B) = B_r(x)$ for some $r > 0$ and $x \in \varphi(U)$. By construction there exists $r' > r$, s.t. $B_{r'}(x) \subseteq \varphi(U)$. So refering to the definition of reg. coord. balls we can just take $B' := \varphi^{-1}(B_{r'}(x))$ and the corresponding coordinate map $\varphi' : B' \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is obtained by composing $\varphi$ with the translation taking $x$ to the origin.

Comment: In this way we obtain from $\mathcal{B}'$ a countable basis of regular coordinate balls for $U$. This can be extended to a basis for the whole of $M$ since smooth manifolds are 2nd countable and admit a countable atlas $A = \{(U_i, \varphi_i)\}$. For this we just take the union of all the respective reg. coord. bases of each $U_i$. I hope this is correct...

Comment: Yes it is! A similar trick is to consider a countable base of coordinate ball( you already know to exists) and taking smaller radious you get regular balls.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding there is nothing special here about $M$ being smooth? The same statement about regular coordinate balls holds for all topological manifolds. The only possible complication with smooth manifolds is we would need to check that our proof does not rely on charts that are not smoothly compatible with our smooth atlas.